# A better way to look for duplicates

Tags: .net, compare, kendo-grid

I'm working a lot with kendogrid and have a kendogrid which has an dropdown in it. There are four rows and I need to validate that none of the rows have selected the same value as any other row have. I'm doing it like this:

```
var pj = 0; var ga = 0; var gt = 0; var empty = 0;
    var existingValues = _.filter($("#configSettingsGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data(), function (config) {
        if (config.Enabled === true) {
            if (config.selectedJackpotType === "Progressive jackpot") {
                pj++
            }
            if (config.selectedJackpotType === "Guaranteed amount") {
                ga++
            }
            if (config.selectedJackpotType === "Guaranteed time") {
                gt++
            }
            if (config.selectedJackpotType === "") {
                empty++
            }
        }
    });
    if (pj > 1 || ga > 1 || gt > 1 || empty > 0) {
        return false;
    }
```

which works since U know these are the values that the user can choose between but I would really like to have a more dynamic solution that if in the future it comes in new type of selectable values the validation can handle that as well. Anyone have a nice way of comparing these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To make it work dynamically for any no. of options, keep a count of each selected option(use an object with key-value pair where key is the option and value is it's count).
- In the end, iterate over each object key and check it's value. If it's greater than `1`, then return `false`, else return `true`. In the below code, I am assuming everything is inside a function or closure.

**CODE:**

```
var hash = {};
_.filter($("#configSettingsGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.data(), function (config) {
    if (config.Enabled === true) {
        hash[config.selectedJackpotType] = hash[config.selectedJackpotType] === undefined ? 1 : hash[config.selectedJackpotType] + 1;
    }
});

var selected_options = Object.keys(hash);

for(let each_option in selected_options){
    if(hash[selected_options[each_option]] > 1){
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```